# Visual Studio C++ compiler tries to compile CUDA C/C++ files

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to make a project I've been working on use CUDA.
At the moment it has four build configs, two (release and debug) which define a compiler symbol so it compiles with CUDA, and two (release and debug) which instead directs it to CPU code.

This is a short version of main.cpp:

```
#ifdef CUDA
#include "CUDACode.cu"
#else
#include "CPUCode.h"
#endif

int main() {
    functionDefinedinBothHeaders(params);
}
```

but for some reason NVCC runs and compiles it fine but then the C++ compiler trys to compile it and that causes many errors that I've managed to circumvent using  `#ifdef __NVCC__` statements but now I have an issue where main.cpp has to use something from a header so I put is outside the `#ifdef __NVCC__` statements and now I get linker error as they are defined twice as NVCC compiles it and the C++ compile does as well

```
error LNK2005: "class boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int,32,351,175,19,3433795303,11,4294967295,7,834054912,15,4293197824,17,1812433253> generator" (?generator@@3V?$mersenne_twister_engine@I$0CA@$0BFP@$0KP@$0BD@$0MMKLIOOH@$0L@$0PPPPPPPP@$06$0DBLGKLAA@$0P@$0PPOFAAAA@$0BB@$0GMAHIJGF@@random@boost@@A) already defined in CUDAStateCalc.cu.obj
```

the .cu files are set to CUDA C/C++ code. How do I stop it from doing that? and is there a better method than what I'm doing?

Comment: I think on VS you could use `#pragma once` to avoid the error, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @RealReza The issue is that both NVCC and MSVC compile it (two seperate compilers) and when it gets to linking they contain some of the same symbols leading to errors

Comment: Do you get the error when compiling with option `-dc` too?

Comment: If you have added `CUDACode.cu` to your project, you should not also include it in `main.cpp`.  Choose one or the other.

Comment: But I need to access a function from CUDACode.cu

Comment: Structuring projects in CUDA isn't any different than structuring a C++ project in VS.  Put your implementation in `CUDACode.cu`.  If you need to access a function defined in `CUDACode.cu` from `main.cpp`, then create a header file (lets call it `header.h`) that contains the function prototype only, and include that header file both in your `main.cpp` and optionally in `CUDACode.cu`.  But you don't want a situation where you are compiling `CUDACode.cu` as a separate module in your project, **and** also including `CUDACode.cu` in `main.cpp`.  That will give multiple definition errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Crovella answered my question in the comments, what I needed to do was have a header function that was included in `main.cpp` and `CUDACode.cu` and contained the function prototype for `functionDefinedinBothHeaders` but `CUDACode.cu` defined it